# Can't switch to the cc fields iframes and fill up the form

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

[image]

Here is the page. I can't share the code of html. please look at the image.
Here is the code I am trying:

```
iframes = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.iframes[1])
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "cardnumber"))).send_keys("4074 6552 3718 4431")
```

Comment: You may not be able to link to the page but you can share the HTML... you have it in the image but in the image we can't do anything with it like try locators. Copy the relevant parts of the HTML and paste them into your question, properly formatted.

Comment: You never mention what the error message, etc. is when you try that code. Copy/paste the error message into your question and properly format it also.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is only 1 IFRAME on the page? You code assumes there is. Have you looked to see if there are nested IFRAMEs?

Comment: there are more than 5 iframes. I need to find the first iframe with the name starts with "__privateStripeFrame"

Comment: Great. That should be added to your question so future readers don't have to read all the comments to get all the relevant info. You should still answer/follow the instructions in my other comments.

Comment: I'm trying to find all the iframes starts with self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@name,'__privateStripeFrame')")))

Is it possible to find element with partial name attribute. because there are some random numbers after __privateStripeFrame. but all frames name starts with __privateStripeFrame

Comment: You still need to edit your question and add all of those details.

Answer (score 1):

Look for specific iframe and switch to it accordingly. But `self` by yourself.
You will need to wait for this iframe to load. Pay attention to the locator I used. You can modify it. It looks for all iframes which names contain `_privateStripeFrame`.
I am not sure if `clear` method is needed in this case. Try to make an input without it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'_privateStripeFrame')]")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@name, '_privateStripeFrame')]")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "cardnumber")))
card_number = driver.find_element_by_name("cardnumber")
card_number.clear().send_keys("4074655237184431")
```

Comment: this error is coming: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //iframe[contains(@name,'_privateStripeFrame') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//iframe[contains(@name,'_privateStripeFrame')' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: problem is iframes name attribute is changing in every request.

Comment: Check again, there was small typo

Comment: @ssharkar It is not a big problem if you know how to apply xpath. You can also use css selector for this purpose.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11hw1wl

I can't reply the code here it's big. please look at the screenshot with marked area. not able to switch to the next frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231196/discussion-between-ssharkar-and-vitaliis).