# Selenium element locating in Google Ads

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using Selenium and I have encountered an issue when I would like to download report from Google ads.

Since I got several accounts in Google ads, I would like to download the transaction report in daily basis in order to have a better control of the credit card limit.

However, when I would like to locate the "Download" button in below pic, seems the click was not in the right place and no report downloaded.
[image]
and the corresponding HTML code
[image]

Since I have figured out it is inside a iframe, I have switched to the frame first but it still doesn't work.

Code:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('embedded-page-containerIframe'))
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframeBody"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]').click
```

How can I achieve it and successfully download the report? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This `xpath` should work:

```
//title[contains(text(),'Download')]
```

Also, replace `click` with `click()`

Check here how to switch to iframe and wait without adding `time.sleep`:
[Can't switch to the cc fields iframes and fill up the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119011/cant-switch-to-the-cc-fields-iframes-and-fill-up-the-form)

Try using: `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`

**Edit**:
to click `div` use:

```
//div[@aria-label='Download']
```

Comment: Hi vitaliis, after I have changed to code to "browser.find_element_by_xpath('//title[contains(text(),"Download")]').click()". An error 'NoSuchElementException' shows. May you please help? Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi vitaliis, I have changed to code to below
`wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5)`
`wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "embedded-page-containerIframe")))`
`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Download']")))`
`browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Download']").click()`

but it show an error of 
`AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'switch_to'`

Comment: You probably forgot to remove old `switch_to`. 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'switch_to' error shows what is wrong.

Comment: Also, change wait time to 10 seconds and try all locators for the button from this and other answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/exWOoVI
My code is as above, may I know where can i remove the old `switch_to`? 
Sorry for asking much question. (bow)

Comment: and the error `AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'switch_to'` occurs in this line `wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "embedded-page-containerIframe")))`

Comment: Can you share the link to the page you are testing? Not the exact one, just similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231672/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-eric-so).

Answer (score 0):

use following `CSS Selector` to click on `Download` button.

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Download']").click()`

---

Since the title element inside svg element you try below xapth.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='title' and text()='Download']").click()
```

Comment: Hi KunduK, Thanks! However, it shows an error = `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size`. May you please assist? (bow)

Comment: You still need to switch to frame